# clearing variables of root view controller when switching tabs programmatically

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller

I have a storyboard/root viewcontroller as the third tab on my app. On that tab the user selects an image, and writes a caption, which are stored as variables. From the root viewcontroller the user is taken to a preview screen via a segue which passes the variables, i.e. image and text. From this screen the user posts the object. From the post button, I am popping the viewcontroller, and programatically navigating to the first tab of my app. That all works, but the problem is when I then navigate back to the third tab, the stored variables are still there, and I'd like them to be cleared out.

I've seen many posts on keeping the variables, but none on how to reset them. I've tried to use viewWillDissapear but I don't want them cleared when I use the segue because I want the user to be able to go back and make some changes if needed.

UPDATED CODE WITH CORRECT ANSWER

```
@IBAction func postButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {




        PostFunction.createPost(image: self.postImage, postText: self.hashtag) { (true) in


            self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0

            let tab3 = self.tabBarController!.viewControllers![2] as! UINavigationController
            let vc = tab3.viewControllers.first as! PostHomeVC
            vc.clear()

            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions on how to "reset" the rootviewcontroller from the above method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am popping the viewcontroller, and programatically navigating to the first tab of my app

before you do the programmatic switch to the first tab do

```
let tab3 = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[2] as! UINavigationController
let vc = tab3.viewControllers.first as! VCName
vc.clear()
```

or

```
let vc = self.navigationController!.viewControllers.first as! VCName
vc.clear()
```

and write that `clear` method inside the vc as you need

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I've been working with the proposed solutions, but not having success. When I implement the above it makes it so the             self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
does not work anymore. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: Just had to change the order up a little, otherwise you were spot on, thanks for the help!